# Некорректное отображение окна программы функцией showFullScreen

Tags: c++, qt

Для отображения главного окна приложения использую вызов `showFullScreen`. До недавнего времени все было нормально, а сейчас вдруг окно стало открываться некорректно. Это проявляется в том, что окно отображается так, как будто рассчитано на монитор с размерами не 16:9, а 4:3, при этом верхняя и нижняя часть окна выходят за границы экрана, а справа остается пустое место.

Под Windows мне удалось справиться с этим, используя вот такой кривой маневр:

```
    w.setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    w.show();
    w.setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

Но под Ubuntu это не срабатывает, окно отображается так, как описано выше.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, и как ее можно решить? Или хотя бы - в какую сторону копать.
Найти совет с помощью гугл, увы, не удалось. Все, что нашел, сводится к использованию той же `showFullScreen`

Comment: Может быть у вас установлены ограничения на размер окна?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Может быть, конечно, но было бы странно. Дело в том, что до изменений приложение открывалось нормально, а после - вот такая ерунда. Но изменения не касались главного окна приложения, заменялась библиотека, обрабатывающая одно из вспомогательных окон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, мне так и не удалось разобраться, в чем же причина такого поведения программы. Но удалось обойти проблему, задав геометрию окна в соответствии с геометрией экрана. Вот такой код заработал и под Windows, и под Ubuntu:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);        
auto ag = a.primaryScreen()->geometry();
w.setMinimumSize(1024,768);
w.setGeometry(ag);
w.showFullScreen();
```